# On gnome (wayland), how to swap ctrl and alt on both sides?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

`gnome-tweak-tools` provides an option to swap left ctrl and alt, but not right ctrl and alt. How should I swap ctrl and alt on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up by editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` and swap the keycode of ctl and alt. However, this change may be lost every time a relevant system package upgrades.